# Upgraded Postgres; how to access now-missing databases?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

My local connection on my Mac (10.9.5) wasn't working to my Postgres (9.3) database (and therefore I couldn't actually export the data), so I tried upgrading it to 9.4. Luckily I can now connect to the database, but... My old databases (and tables, views, etc.) are now missing...

Is it possible to recover these? How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Before every major upgrade you need to do a backup/restore. The databases are there but 9.4 does not recognize them. The easiest way would be to remove 9.4, reinstall 9.3, do a full backup, then install 9.4 again and do a restore.